# Fabric-CA Cannot read property 'url' of undefined

Tags: url, hyperledger-fabric, ca, hyperledger-chaincode, hyperledger-fabric-ca

During fabcar_router coding, the caURL states that url is undefined. There was no problem with npm import.
I couldn't find any problem.
Has anyone experienced a similar error?

**Error Message**

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined

```
/home/uyh/4jes/MyWeb/routes/fabcar_router.js:14
const caURL = ccp.certificateAuthorities["ca.example.com"].url;
                                                           ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined
    **at Object.<anonymous> (/home/uyh/4jes/MyWeb/routes/fabcar_router.js:14:60)**
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/uyh/4jes/MyWeb/server.js:10:20) 
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

**fabcar_router.js**

> const caURL = ccp.certificateAuthorities["ca.example.com"].url;

```
const express = require('express'); 
const router = express.Router(); 
const fs = require('fs'); 
const path = require('path'); 

const FabricCAServices = require('fabric-ca-client'); 
const { FileSystemWallet, X509WalletMixin, Gateway } = require('fabric-network'); 

const ccpPath = path.resolve(__dirname, '..' , 'a', 'connection.json'); 
const ccpJSON = fs.readFileSync(ccpPath, 'utf8'); 
const ccp = JSON.parse(ccpJSON); 

// Create a new CA client for interacting with the CA. 
const caURL = ccp.certificateAuthorities["ca.example.com"].url;
const ca = new FabricCAServices(caURL); 

// Create a new file system based wallet for managing identities. 
const walletPath = path.join(process.cwd(), 'wallet'); 
const wallet = new FileSystemWallet(walletPath); console.log(`Wallet path: ${walletPath}`); 
console.log(`Wallet path: ${walletPath}`);
```

**package.json**

```
 "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "fabric-ca-client": "^2.2.0",
    "fabric-client": "^1.4.17",
    "fabric-network": "^2.2.5"
  }
```

Comment: Check out your `connection.json` file.

Comment: Maybe it fails when loading `connection.json` or `connection.json` missing `url` config in the `ca.example.com` section